# initialize unique_ptr const reference from a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, unique-ptr

I initialized an unique_ptr with an Object. As i want to pass a reference of it to a function and don't let the function to change the object contents, I have to pass `unique_ptr<const MyObject>&` to it. But gcc 5.4 doesn't let me to initialize `unique_ptr<const MyObject>&` from `uinque_ptr<MyObject>`.

Example Code:

```
class Foo{public int x;};
unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());
foo->x = 5;

// User shouldn't be able to touch bar contents.
unique_ptr<const Foo>& bar = foo;
```

C++ error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::unique_ptr<const Foo>&’ from expression of type ‘std::unique_ptr<Foo>’
```

So is there any reasonable way to do it?

Comment: You could provide the raw pointer from `foo.get()` as `const Foo*` for the client.

Comment: If a function isn't allowed to modify the object anyway, what's the reason behind passing a smart pointer instead of a regular pointer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If i provide regular const pointer to user, he can delete it.

Comment: @hamed1soleimani Fair point.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If i provide regular const pointer to user, he can delete it.

Comment: @hamed1soleimani With enough determination, a user can delete a pointer from inside `unique_ptr`, too, so it's not a new problem.

Comment: @hamed1soleimani: C++ guards against Murphy, not against Machiavelli.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues:

- How to `constify` the referent of a `unique_ptr`.
- How to pass a non-owning pointer to a function.

The reasonable way to pass a non-owning pointer is to pass a raw pointer:

```
some_function( my_unique_ptr.get() );
```

Or if it can't be null then you can dereference the pointer and pass a reference,

```
some_function( *my_unique_ptr )
```

This means that the constification is pretty much irrelevant to the main issue, but still, here's how to do that also:

```
unique_ptr<Foo>         p{ new Foo() };
unique_ptr<const Foo>   q{ move( p ) };    // Moves ownership!
```

Comment: If i pass the pointer user could delete it. Event it's const pointer. Also i don't want to release ownership of the object by moving it. Only i want to pass a reference of the unique_ptr

Comment: It it can't be null then you can dereference the pointer and pass a reference, `some_function( *my_unique_ptr )`. If it can be null, the general case, then just pass the raw pointer. By convention, **a raw pointer does not carry ownership**: it would be wrong of the called function to delete it.

Comment: Amended the answer with that advice.

Comment: @cheers-and-hth-alf Yeah, I don't want to pass raw pointer of it, because user could delete it. But as i'm sure that it's not empty i could dereference it and pass `cosnt Foo&`.

Answer (score 2):

A [valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42606158/7571258) has already been posted.

I just want to provide some additional ideas for the case that the pointer could be empty.

**Idea 1:** Wrap the pointer into a `std::shared_ptr` with empty deleter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo{ int x; };

void Fun( std::shared_ptr<const Foo> p ) {
    if( p )     
        std::cout << "p.x: " << p->x << std::endl;
    //won't compile:
    //delete p;
}

int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());
    foo->x = 5;

    std::shared_ptr<const Foo> bar( foo.get(), []( const Foo* ){} );
    Fun( bar );

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83fad9e695eeefeb)

**Idea 2:** Use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) to pass a reference but still allow it to be empty. Unfortunately this doesn't work with [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) because `std::optional` doesn't allow reference arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct Foo{ int x; };

using OptionalFooConstRef = boost::optional<Foo const&>;

void Fun( OptionalFooConstRef p ){
    if( p )
        std::cout << "p.x: " << p->x << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "no foo\n";
    //won't compile:
    //delete p;
}

int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());
    foo->x = 5;

    Fun( foo ? OptionalFooConstRef( *foo ) : boost::none );

    std::unique_ptr<Foo> nofoo;
    Fun( nofoo ? OptionalFooConstRef( *nofoo ) : boost::none );

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f15c77c02ec6474)

**Conclusion:**

I would prefer `boost::optional` because it better expresses the intention.